# Is it possible to create an XmlElement with two xml namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have to generate XML like the below:

```
<foo:document xmlns="http://www.example.com/xmlns" xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/xmlns/foo-version1">
    <foo:bar foo:baz="true" />
</foo:document>
```

How can I generate this document with `System.Xml.XmlDocument` in c#?

Comment: Any particular reason you need `XmlDocument` rather than `XDocument`? LINQ to XML is *much* cleaner IMO in terms of namespace support.

Comment: Did you look at [How do I add multiple namespaces to the root element with XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/331568/3744182) and [How to add attributes to xml using XmlDocument in c# .net CF 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3405284/3744182) and [Creating an XML element with a namespace with XmlDocument.CreateElement()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689095/3744182)?  Do those answer your question?  If not, what have you tried so far, that did not work?

Comment: @dbc : Did you try creating the node?  The default namespace is not the last namespace and Net library want to see the default as the last attribute.

Comment: @jdweng - yes, I did.  I was able to get the required output with both `XmlDocument` and `XDocument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
var fooNs = "http://www.example.com/xmlns/foo-version1";
var defNs = "http://www.example.com/xmlns";

var doc = new XmlDocument();

// Create and add the root element
var root = doc.CreateElement("foo", "document", fooNs);
doc.AppendChild(root);

// Add the default namespace (do note the root element is not in this namespace)
var defAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
defAttr.Value = defNs;
root.Attributes.Append(defAttr);

// Create the <foo:bar> element
var bar = doc.CreateElement("foo", "bar", fooNs);
var bazAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("foo", "baz", fooNs);
bazAttr.Value = XmlConvert.ToString(true);
bar.Attributes.Append(bazAttr);

// Add it to the root
root.AppendChild(bar);
```

Notes:

- When creating `XmlElement` and `XmlAttribute` nodes in a namespace, always prefer to use the `Create()` overloads that take a prefix, a localName and a namespaceURI:

  - [`XmlDocument.CreateElement(String, String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlDocument_CreateElement_System_String_System_String_System_String_)
  - [`XmlDocument.CreateAttribute(String, String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createattribute?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlDocument_CreateAttribute_System_String_System_String_System_String_)

  From a semantic point of view, what really matters is the node local name and namespace; the prefix is just a lookup to find a namespace declaration in scope.
- Notice I didn't explicitly add the `xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/xmlns/foo-version1"` attribute?  It is unnecessary to do this since the root element was created using the required namespace and prefix via `doc.CreateElement("foo", "document", fooNs)`.  The framework (`XmlWriter`) will automatically emit the `xmlns:foo` attribute as it writes the `XmlDocument` to XML.

  If for some reason you need to explicitly create the namespace attribute, you can do it as follows:

  ```
  // The following is redundant as the framework (XmlWriter) will add the necessary
  // xmlns:foo attribute as the XmlDocument is being written.  If you need to do it anway 
  // (e.g. to control the order) you can do it as follows.
  // (But note that XML attributes are unordered according to the XML specification, for details
  // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746224/in-xml-is-the-attribute-order-important)
  var xmlnsNs = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/";

  var fooAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns", "foo", xmlnsNs);
  fooAttr.Value = fooNs;
  root.Attributes.Append(fooAttr);
  ```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ttsRgm).

Incidentally, as written in comments, it's much easier to do this with [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview):

```
XNamespace fooNs = "http://www.example.com/xmlns/foo-version1";
XNamespace defNs = "http://www.example.com/xmlns";

var root = new XElement(fooNs + "document"
                        // Add the namespace declarations with your desired prefixes.  Be sure to pass them into the constructor.
                        , new XAttribute("xmlns", defNs.ToString())
                        , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "foo", fooNs.ToString())
                        // And add any required content.  The content can be passed into the constructor, or added later. 
                        , new XElement(fooNs + "bar", new XAttribute(fooNs + "baz", true)));
```

Notes:

- With LINQ to XML you *never* need to worry about the namespace prefix of an `XElement` or `XAttribute`.  Just create them with the correct namespace and local name as encapsulated by [`XName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xname?view=netframework-4.8).  The framework (`XmlWriter`) will automatically emit all necessary namespace attributes as it writes.

  But if you do need to configure namespaces for some reason you can construct appropriate `XAttribute` objects and then pass them into the [`XElement` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XElement__ctor_System_Xml_Linq_XName_System_Object___).
- For further reading see *[How to: Create a Document with Namespaces (C#) (LINQ to XML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-document-with-namespaces-linq-to-xml)*.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gnk1CP).

Answer (score 0):

The Net library want the default namespace (without the prefix) to be the last namespace.  I usually just use the Parse method which has less restrictions.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<foo:document xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/xmlns\" xmlns:foo=\"http://www.example.com/xmlns/foo-version1\">" +
                         "   <foo:bar foo:baz=\"true\" />" +
                         "</foo:document>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        }
    }
}
```